# User form in separate class; main ends before action can be selected

Tags: java, forms

I used "free design" layout (manager) in Netbeans IDE to visually create a form with buttons, text boxes, checkboxes, etc. It was easy; looks great. I was happy.

Two buttons do exactly what I want. One ["Browse..."] opens a `FileChooser` `showOpenDialog`, which then fills one of the textboxes with the chosen directory. The EXIT button also works. I was overjoyed. There's a 3rd button that makes big stuff happen, but I'm confused about something, so it's on hold.

So I copied the (uneditable/locked) code to a file named GUIform.java (so I could edit it). The form is displayed and works as described above. The "main" file (Search.java) looks like this:

```
package guiform; // This line also appears in GUIform.java.

public class Search  {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater
    (new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          GUIform myGUI = new GUIform();
          System.out.println("X");
        }
    }
    );
  }
}
```

That file used to consist of `package, class, main`, and the `GUIform` and `println` lines in the body of the `run` method. The `println` executes before the form is "dismissed". A little confused research made me add the `invokeLater` and `Runnable` stuff but nothing changed.

My question is, "**How do I make `main` wait for the user to submit the form?**" Nothing good can happen until that happens and if `println` does its thing before the form even has time to be displayed, the bigger plans are not going to work since the form input is required.

(This seems a most fundamental situation, but my two texts total nearly 2000 pages and most examples are pretty sparse.)

Comment: Well... I'm gonna say it works up to a point. I've added code to GUIform.java to catch mouse clicks AND the SEARCH button DOES do what it should EXCEPT I gotta use regular expressions instead of Windows filename patterns.

My newbie status requires me to wait FIVE MORE HOURS to post what I REALLY want to post--a detailed resolution. Since that's 1:00am, I guess I'll do so first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I added code to GUIform.java to catch mouse clicks AND the SEARCH button DOES do what it should with the user-entered Windows-based filename pattern (which I convert to regular expressions).

Here's main:

```
package guiform;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class Search  {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

    GUIform myGUI = new GUIform() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      }
    };    
  }
}
```

And here's the most important addition to GUI, code for the SEARCH button, which I gathered mostly from generated code from the form creation tool:

```
  private void jbSearchActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    EventQueue.invokeLater
    (new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

          FileVisitor visitor = new FileVisitor();

          try {
                Path startPath = Paths.get(GUIform.getjtRootNode());
                Files.walkFileTree(startPath, visitor);
          }
          catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Sh00t!!" + ex);
          }
        }
    }
    );

  }
```

What I only just learned from "Java all-in-one for Dummies" is that, indeed, any GUI-based app MUST have at LEAST TWO threads. What I didn't realize until just then is that I had finally done so by what felt like tortured trial and error, which is beginning to make perfect[-ish] sense.